# execute the promise function in the method. "res" prints out as "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I ran into problems with element-ui when I executed the promise function in the method. "res" prints out as "undefined" and jumps into ".catch", but in Network the api returns the data normally.Finally I failed to delete

```js
deleteTradeMark(row) {
      this.$confirm(`此操作将永久删除${row.tmName}, 是否继续?`, '提示', {
        confirmButtonText: '确定',
        cancelButtonText: '取消',
        type: 'warning'
      }).then(async () => {
       let res =  await this.$API.trademark.reqDeleteTradeMark(row.id)
        console.log(res)   //  undefind
        if(res.code===200){
          this.$message({
            type: 'success',
            message: '删除成功!'
          });
          this.getTradeMark(this.list.length>1?this.page:this.page-1)
        }

      }).catch(() => {
        this.$message({
          type: 'info',
          message: '已取消删除'
        });
      });
    }
```

```
 export  const  reqDeleteTradeMark=(id)=>{
  request({url:`/api/admin/product/baseTrademark/remove/${id}`,method:'delete'})
}
```

[image]
The api returns code:"200" and delete:" Deleted successfully ".

Why do all the other promises work, is it because of  ".then" ?

Comment: Just because the network shows data in the response doesn't mean your code uses it correctly. What does the `this.$API.trademark.reqDeleteTradeMark` function do? Please [edit] your question to show that code

Comment: It is a request method for deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `return` before `request` in `reqDeleteTradeMarkq method.

```
export  const  reqDeleteTradeMark=(id)=>{
      return request({url:`/api/admin/product/baseTrademark/remove/${id}`,method:'delete'})
}
```

Comment: How do I know when to add```return```, and some requests API are fine without a return。                       ```export  const reqTradeMarkList =(page,limit)=>request({url:`/api/admin/product/baseTrademark/${page}/${limit}`,method:'get'})```

Comment: Well, this is a grammar about `arrow function`. If your `arrow function` have  only one line, and you want return its value, you can write like this: `() => request('')`. It sames as `() => { return request('') }`. I recommend you to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score -1):

**async-await** grammar act on **Promise**, your function **reqDeleteTradeMark** not return **Promise**
[async-await-grammar](https://javascript.info/async-await)